# C# fields and properties

Tags: c#, properties, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

I don't understand the difference between field and properties in a class.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **field** is a storage location for information. For example, if the field is of type `int`, it stores a 32-bit integer (a number from around minus 4 billion to around plus 4 billion).

A **property** is almost like a method or a pair of methods. It’s just code. No storage. For example, instead of

```
public int FortySeven
{
    get
    {
        return 47;
    }
}
```

you could also write

```
public int GetFortySeven()
{
    return 47;
}
```

and it would be more or less the same thing; the only difference is that you write `FortySeven` (no parentheses) but `GetFortySeven()` (with parentheses).

Of course, properties can also have a *setter*, which means that

```
public int FortySeven
{
    set
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

is pretty much the same thing as

```
public void SetFortySeven(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

and now instead of `FortySeven = 47` you write `SetFortySeven(47)`, but otherwise it is functionally the same.

An **automatically-implemented property** looks like this:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

This code declares **both a field and a property**, but the field is invisible and you can only access the property. It uses the invisible field for its storage.